# Reporting structure --> column level summary formula aka, how many accounts have no invitation

Tags: lightning, custom-reports

so i have a propblem regarding Reporting Some Numbers :

in Our Structure to All accounts, some have contacts and from some of these Contacts the field we Called : customer portal status,  is either invited, access or nothing (external portal).

so now if i want to report on how many accounts we have that actually have no access, it seems i cannot do that because the report always schows the record count of the Contacts which can be up to 10 per account.

is there a possibility, like a column lvl formula or somethin to actually count how many accounts there are in this report so it can be displayed as a number inside of a dashboard ?

PS : rowcount sums up the Contacts and i need the number of the accounts

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Did you try using count [distant values](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.reports_count_unique_values.htm&type=5) in the report

Answer (score 0):

In the report you can display in column the id of the account

[image: Column account id]

Then In Group lines you can group by account id

[image]

You will have the account number

[image]